# How to do rounding in moneyrails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, money-rails

i want to modify the moneyrails gem like this(in case of USD). if it is above 15.01 it should round to 16) (eg: 15.01 or 15.10 or 15.50 or 15.90 it should exchange to 16)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In an initializer: configure it like this:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
  config.rounding_mode = BigDecimal::ROUND_UP
end
```

Comment: then how i should call in view page? `humanized_money_with_symbol product.price.exchange_to(@cart.currency)`